# jQuery / CSS combo noticeable lag in prepend & display:none

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, breadcrumbs

So I've begun playing with fontawesome & breadcrumbs at the same time & being the newb I am, I've got something that's cool but there's a bit of a hiccup that's annoying with what we're doing on our breadcrumbs - we're replacing the site's name with the home icon & there's a noticeable lag on the operations completing - the method that we're using is as follows:

Called in functions:

```
function my_theme_breadcrumbs() {
    echo '<a href="';
    echo get_option('home');
    echo '">';
    bloginfo('name');
    echo "</a>";
        if (is_category() || is_single()) {
            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&#187;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            the_category(' &bull; ');
                if (is_single()) {
                    echo " &nbsp;&nbsp;&#187;&nbsp;&nbsp; ";
                    the_title();
                }
        } elseif (is_page()) {
            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&#187;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            echo the_title();
        } elseif (is_search()) {
            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&#187;&nbsp;&nbsp;Search Results for... ";
            echo '"<em>';
            echo the_search_query();
            echo '</em>"';
        }
    }
function display_breadcrumbs() {
?><div class="breadcrumbs"><?php my_theme_breadcrumbs(); ?></div><?php
    }

add_action('my_theme_hook_after_header','display_breadcrumbs');
```

Header:

```
<div id="breadcrumbs"><?php my_theme_breadcrumbs (); ?></div>
```

Footer:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#breadcrumbs').prepend('<a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" class="homecrumb">&#xf015</a>')
                        });
```

Style:

```
#breadcrumbs a:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
}
```

I realize that this is a bit messy because of how it's rendering, so any input you folks have is certainly welcome.

-Jc

Comment: Nobody will be able to test this, because it's an incomplete PHP program. Showing the resulting HTML is better. Or even (as a last resort) a link to your website, so we can take a look.

Comment: I was afraid that may be the case - I was hoping that someone would be able to tell me how my approach was flawed based on how I was implementing - I don't think it's going to be a deal breaker for what we're up to, it's just a minor detail that I'd like to have resolved.
The resulting HTML is pretty sparse, at any rate, since we're just dealing with breadcrumbs, so I don't know how much that would even add.